# Umbraco content problems after migrate from 7.15 to 12.3 version

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco12

I was able to migrate the content of my Umbraco V7 site to V12.3. Currently because i'm not familiar with the Umbraco, i need some hints to determine if the content is migrated successfully.
Currently i have completely empty .NET 7 project with Umbraco 12.3 installed, nothing from the code is transferred on this stage.
The steps what i followed are these mention in the accepted answer:
[followed steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366507/what-is-the-correct-upgrade-path-from-umbraco-version-7-to-version-12)
Problems what im seeing and trying to resolve are:

1. Page Title showing me [object Object]
2. Page components are empty and "Add content" button is disabled

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdFdH.png)

[page name type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJs5m.png)

[related links missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqH7b.png)

Currently im out of ideas.

Comment: I have added some additional notes to answer your new question. If my answer has helped you, remember to upvote it and if it has helped to resolve your problem, please remember to select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What data type are you using for your Page Title? Could that be Nested Content? If yes, then make sure that your Nested Content data type setup is correct again after your data migration. You can check your old v7 project to see your Nested Content setup.

Here are some screenshots from one of my projects that I have upgraded to help you.

PS: Things have changed a lot for Nested Content from v7 to v12. The Nested Content is [deprecated in Umbraco v11 and it is going to be removed in Umbraco v13](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/110618-does-nested-content-data-type-was-removed-from-v11#comment-342437). You should consider using Block List or Block grid for future Data Types.

Screenshots from my project:

My Document type that is using a Nested Content data type.

[image]

After my upgrade, these document types were missing in my Nested Content setup.

[image]

After checking the Permissions and making sure the Is and Element Type is checked for these document types, I could reference them in my Nested Content again and the problem disappeared.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please check my question again i added a picture what shows the type of the Page Name, also checked the type of Page Components and there is Umbraco.NestedContent type

Comment: For your Page Name, you are using "Vorto Textfield" data type - your next step should be to go to Settings>Data Types in Umbraco backoffice and find this "Vorto Textfield" Data Type and check if the setup is correct for this data type. Most likely your setup is not right now after the data migration. You can compare the setup with your old website.

Comment: I have done a bit of investigation for you about the Vorto data type that you are using. It looks like this is a migration error that you're seeing, it still seems like a setup issue and there is an Umbraco forum question about a similar problem, probably not a Nested Content issue though. Take a look at these links: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-8/97865-vorto-to-language-variant-in-v8
https://github.com/teeto/Vorto-migration-for-Umbraco-8

Comment: The suggestions what u mention about Vorto and nested content fixed my issues what i was mention in the original question. I think i have to fix one last thing before proceed to the next versions, can u please check the question again, i added a picture "related links missing", there u can see i don't have any links after upgrade. Do u have any idea why? The data type is "Multi Url Picker", before in V7 version was "RelatedLinks2"

Comment: I am glad my answers have helped you to fix this problem. In order to proceed, please upvote and accept this answer as the correct answer and ask a new question for the new problem.

With regards to your new problem, check your data types and setups for them, similar to what you have done so far. If you still can't fix the problem, then create a new question on Stackoverflow - you can reference this question in your new question if it helps.